# Lazy loading isn't working for the latest item created

Tags: database, entity-framework, lazy-loading

I have a repository for adding projects, and when I retrieve all items from the database, all of them except the last added item are represented as 'Castle.Proxies.ProjectProxy.' I'm wondering why this happens and what steps I can take to ensure that everything is loaded using lazy loading.

Here is example of code:

```
var addedProject = await _projectRepository.AddAsync(projectToAdd);
await _projectRepository.SaveAsync();
var userProjects = await _projectRepository.GetAllAsync()
```

```
public class ProjectRepository : Repository<Project>, IProjectRepository
{
    public ProjectRepository(TeamHubDbContext TeamHubDbContext)
        : base(TeamHubDbContext) { }
}
```

```
public abstract class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity>
    where TEntity : class, new()
{
    protected readonly TeamHubDbContext TeamHubDbContext;

    protected Repository(TeamHubDbContext socialNetworkContext)
    {
        TeamHubDbContext = socialNetworkContext;
    }

    public virtual async Task<List<TEntity>> GetAllAsync()
    {
        return await TeamHubDbContext.Set<TEntity>().ToListAsync();
    }

    public async Task<TEntity> AddAsync(TEntity entity)
    {
        return (await TeamHubDbContext.AddAsync(entity)).Entity;
    }


    public virtual async Task SaveAsync()
    {
        await TeamHubDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

```
public partial class TeamHubDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Project> Projects { get; set; }

    public TeamHubDbContext(DbContextOptions options)
        : base(options)
    {
        Database.EnsureCreated();
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
    }
}
```

I have taken the necessary steps, including using 'UseLazyLoadingProxies()' and making sure properties are marked as 'virtual' to enable lazy loading. However, despite these measures, the expected behavior is not being achieved.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the function definitions for `AddAsync` and `GetAllAsync` from your repository class?

Comment: @Luke, I did. Help me, please.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the issue was. I was initially confused because lazy loading worked in my other project but not in the current one. It turned out that in the previous project, I had checked all parent entities before creating the dependent one, so everything necessary was already inside the DbContext.